# Speeding up connection to MS SQL Server in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sql-server, performance

Currently when I try to connect to a SQL database in QGIS it takes a bout 30 seconds for all features in the database to load.

I have over 100 tables with geometry columns. When I try to connect to sql server it takes some time to read the table geometries and srid from SQL Server. I have seen the implementation of a geometry_column table in SQL Server for QGIS before. Is this still the most effective approach?

Comment: How many features and what type of features we are talking about ?

Comment: Please edit the question in response to comments requesting clarification.  It's not fair to those who would answer to need to scan comments for critical details.  Note that tables and features are different entities -- do you mean 450 features or 450 tables?  How is the user schema significant?  (Note that loading data tables as the 'sde' user is a violation of best practice, with an increased chance of database corruption).  Since you mention ArcSDE use, how long does it take ArcGIS to connect to the same instance?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Vince. I can confirm that I have over 100 tables with geometry columns. When I try to connect to sql server it takes some time to read the table geometries and srid from SQL Server. I have seen the implementation of a geometry_column table in SQL Server for QGIS before. Is this still the most effective approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create geometry_columns table in dbo schema and populate it with all table informations like name,schema, srid and type of geometry.

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[geometry_columns]    Script Date: 30.08.2016. 20:39:57 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[geometry_columns](
    [f_table_catalog] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [f_table_schema] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [f_table_name] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [f_geometry_column] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [coord_dimension] [int] NOT NULL,
    [srid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [geometry_type] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [geometry_columns_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [f_table_catalog] ASC,
    [f_table_schema] ASC,
    [f_table_name] ASC,
    [f_geometry_column] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: What if you don't have write access to the db? I just want to list all the tables - I know which ones are spatial and which I want to open, so surely I should be able to override that initial scan of all tables, and if QGIS really wants to scan, then it can do that after I select a table